# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") in Python

Tags: python, integer, tuples, concatenation, typeerror

I'm going to need your help with this constant tuple error I keep getting. Seems that it is a common mathematical error that many have. I have read almost every instance of TypeError including 'not int', 'not list', 'not float' etc. Yet I have failed to figure out why I get it.

I have written the below code that allows you to enter the sum of random number and in the end it calculates your success ratio. So I have a counter "right=right+1" to count my correct answers. Seems as if Python doesn't like that.

Here is what I have written:

```
import random 
#the main function
def main():
    counter, studentName, averageRight, right, answer, number1, number2 = declareVariables() 
    studentName = inputNames()

    while counter < 10:
        number1, number2 = getNumber()
        answer = getAnswer(number1, number2, answer)
        right = checkAnswer(number1, number2, answer, right)
        counter = counter + 1
    results(right, averageRight)
    displayInfo(studentName, right, averageRight)

def declareVariables():
    counter = 0
    studentName = 'NO NAME'
    averageRight = 0.0
    right = 0.0
    answer = 0.0
    number1 = 0
    number2 = 0
    return counter, studentName, averageRight, right, answer, number1, number2
    
def inputNames():
    studentName = raw_input('Enter Student Name: ')
    return studentName
    
def getNumber():
    number1 = random.randint(1, 500)
    number2 = random.randint(1, 500)
    return number1, number2

def getAnswer(number1, number2, answer):
    print 'What is the answer to the following equation'
    print number1
    print '+'
    print number2
    answer = input('What is the sum: ')
    return answer
    
def checkAnswer(number1, number2, answer, right):
    if answer == number1+number2:
        print 'Right'
        right = right + 1
    else:
        print 'Wrong'
        
    return right, answer
    
def results(right, averageRight):
    averageRight = right/10
    return averageRight
    
    

def displayInfo(studentName, right, averageRight):
    print 'Information for student: ',studentName
    print 'The number right: ',right
    print 'The average right is: ', averageRight
    
# calls main
main()
```

and I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Lab7-4.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "Lab7-4.py", line 15, in main
    right = checkAnswer(number1, number2, answer, right)
  File "Lab7-4.py", line 52, in checkAnswer
    right = right + 1
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `checkAnswer()` function returns a *tuple*:

```
def checkAnswer(number1, number2, answer, right):
    if answer == number1+number2:
        print 'Right'
        right = right + 1
    else:
        print 'Wrong'

    return right, answer
```

Here `return right, answer` returns a tuple of two values. Note that it's the comma that makes that expression a tuple; parenthesis are optional in most contexts.

You assign this return value to `right`:

```
right = checkAnswer(number1, number2, answer, right)
```

making `right` a tuple here.

Then when you try to add `1` to it again, the error occurs. You don't change `answer` within the function, so there is no point in returning the value here; remove it from the `return` statement:

```
def checkAnswer(number1, number2, answer, right):
    if answer == number1+number2:
        print 'Right'
        right = right + 1
    else:
        print 'Wrong'

    return right
```

Answer (score 2):

```
right = checkAnswer(number1, number2, answer, right)
```

You are assigning what is returned by `checkAnswer`. But you are returning a tuple from it.

```
return right, answer
```

So, after the first iteration `right` becomes a tuple. And when it reaches

```
right = right + 1
```

the second time, it fails to add an int to a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your `averageRight` gives the right result. So I fixed the code. I am using IDLE 3.5.2 so some syntax might seem little different (for example `print()`). So below is the code. You are welcome :)

```
import random 
#the main function
def main():
    counter, studentName, averageRight, right, answer, number1, number2 = declareVariables() 
    studentName = inputNames()

    while counter < 10:
        number1, number2 = getNumber()
        answer = getAnswer(number1, number2, answer)
        right = checkAnswer(number1, number2, answer, right)
        counter = counter + 1

    A=results(right, averageRight)
    displayInfo(studentName, right, A)

def declareVariables():
    counter = 0
    studentName = 'NO NAME'
    averageRight = 0.0
    right = 0
    answer = 0
    number1 = 0
    number2 = 0
    return counter, studentName, averageRight, right, answer, number1, number2

def inputNames():
    studentName = input('Enter Student Name: ')
    return studentName

def getNumber():
    number1 = random.randint(1, 500)
    number2 = random.randint(1, 500)
    return number1, number2

def getAnswer(number1, number2, answer):
    print ('What is the answer to the following equation')
    print (number1)
    print ('+')
    print (number2)
    answer = int(input('What is the sum: ')) #input would be a int. without adding the int it would make answer a string instead of int. which was reason why it was giving 'wrong' 
    return answer

def checkAnswer(number1, number2, answer, right):
    if answer==number1+number2:
        print ('Right')
        right = right + 1
    else:
        print ('Wrong')

    return right

def results(right, averageRight):
    averageRight = right/10
    return averageRight



def displayInfo(studentName, right, A):
    print ('Information for student: ',studentName)
    print ('The number right: ',right)
    print ('The average right is: ', A)

# calls main
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `rightFloat = float(right[0] + 1)` and just reference `rightFloat`. Just a workaround in case you get lazy.

Comment: Did you actually read the OP code? `right` is meant to be a number throughout, the fact that it becomes a tuple is a surprise, *not* the goal.

Comment: Then in that case take the first value of the tuple and add the one to it. Not hard.

Comment: and what about the first call where `right` is set to `0.0`? Instead of fixing the symptom, fix the actual problem.

Comment: Point taken. But then again You could just do `intRight = right[0] + 1` and then just use `intRight` wherever needed.

Comment: Sorry not int. use a float

Comment: Or a decimal if really necessary.

Comment: But the problem here is that one function returns a tuple because the OP misunderstood some syntax. Fixing that means there is no tuple *at all* and the problem goes away.

Comment: Tackling the problem is better than fixing sub-problems it creates. Agreed. Okay, disregard my answer please. Just a workaround if you get lazy.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t understand were is the problem in this code but all time show "Exception has occurred: TypeError
can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple"

```
C=  (float(10))
F= (float((C * 1,8) + 32),1)
while C<=100:
 print(F)
 C += 10
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31787455)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

When trying to concatenate **`tuple` type** and **`int` type** as shown below:

```py
    # tuple # int
print((1, 2) + 3)
```

So, I changed **`int` type** to **`tuple` type** as shown below:

```py
print((1, 2) + (3,))
```

Then, the error above was solved:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```